# Images mix when loading in UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have an app which build on Xcode objective-c , it has a tableview that load images and some info from MySql using PHP. Everything is good except the images, when ever I scroll the table down it takes long time and it mix the Images (image A goes in image B) for seconds and then it become in its position, especially when I scroll the table too fast:

her is my code:

```
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock

{

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if ( !error )
{
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
completionBlock(YES,image);
} else{
completionBlock(NO,nil);
}
}];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

NSString *one = listObjects.theUserId; // the listObjects where is store my info and the images Url
    NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:one];


if (listObjects.image) {
cell.myImageView.image = listObjects.image;

} else {

// set default user image while image is being downloaded
cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage.png"];

// download the image asynchronously
[self downloadImageWithURL:myUrl completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
if (succeeded) {

// change the image in the cell
cell.myImageView.image = image;
// cache the image for use later (when scrolling up)
listObjects.image = image;
}

}];

}


return cell;


}
```

Please check my code, do I need to add anything?
Thanks

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'll keep you up to date if anything comes up. Btw I have tried using -(void)prepareForReuse and still nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is viable for you, I would load all the images in an array before loading the tableview.

In my opinion, a talbeview is only meant for displaying data, not fetching it (which is what is  being done here).

Instead of having an array of NSStrings objets, create your custom object class and give it a nice name and some properties that you would need. For example :

`Student` is my class, inheriting from NSObject

its properties are

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *school;
@property (weak, nonatomic) int *age;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImage *picture;
```

When it's done, create a method that loads all the data you need online and create custom objects out of it. I'm skipping all the download part since you probably know this. If you don't, using AFNetworking is indeed a good idea, as suggest on another answer by Georgio.

I haven't done this in a long time but it's very common and easy, it will be something simple like `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithURL:YOURURL];` or imageWithData:  and your Data comes from something you've got from an URL...

Anyway, you get your data of images like you do now, just somewhere else ! Then, create your `Student` objects with whatever you've fetched online, and then fill your tableview with an array of those objects. Once you've got everything nice and tidy, call

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

and in your `cellForRow`  :

```
Student *student = [myArrayOfFetchedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.image       = student.image;
cell.title       = student.name;
cell.subtitle    = student.school;
return cell;
```

You could/should totally use a custom cell for more appopriate display of your specific data. That's another question and another tutorial.

By doing this, you will ensure that :

- All your photos are loaded before the tableview is loaded
- There will be no gimmick/lag/glitch because we're always dealing with the same objets.

Doing asynch jobs in the cellforrow is just asking for trouble and will destroy your user's experience.

Comment: Thanks Zil, I am not good enough to use your way. I will try the other answer if it is working. Otherwise I will learn your way.

Comment: Its fairly easy even for a beginner, which I am myself. On top of that, it's good pratice, and definitly a good habit to take ;)
I very strongly suggest you try that, even if it takes 10 times the time (which should be about 2 hours if you've never done it, ever), you'll get much more out of it

Comment: Good ! All the hard work you learn now will make your Life easier later :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to fix the problem. The best one is loading the images with AFNetworking. You can find the github project here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking 
Just copy "AFNetworking" folder to your project and from the "UIKit+AFNetworking" folder copy "ImageView+AFNetworking.h" and "ImageView+AFNetworking.m" (you can also use AFNetworking with many others elements of UIKit". 
Then import "ImageView+AFNetworking.h" to your class

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
```

And to load the images add this in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, use:

```
[cell.myImageView setImageWithURL:myURL placeholderImage:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try it as soon as I reach home.